# Are Visual C++ library DLLs localized?

Tags: c++, windows, deployment, localization, runtime

We include the Visual C++ runtime libraries when deploying our c++ application on Windows, i.e. using merge modules like Microsoft_VC90_CRT_x86.msm.

Do we need a localized version of those libraries when targeting other languages (Spanish, Portuguese, German, etc.), or are they generic?

If you could provide a link "straight from the source," that would be most helpful. Any practical experience is welcome as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CRT is not localizable.  There are a handful of error messages, all hard-coded in English with #define statements.  You'll find them in crt\src\cmsgs.h

The only one that a user is ever liable to see is

> This application has requested the
>   Runtime to terminate it in an unusual
>   way.
>  Please contact the
>   application's support team for more
>   information.

A useless message, translating it doesn't make it any clearer.

Answer (score 3):

MFC has localized DLLs and a merge module to install the appropriate one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235264.aspx

The main Visual C++ runtime doesn't appear to have that.

Comment: Yep this looks right to me, cannot find anything outside MFC that's localized.  Makes sense, since the only language that CRT (Standard Library) depend on is C (C++).

Comment: The real problem with MFC is the fact that they are localized into several languages only. For example (AFAIK) there are no Polish localization...

Comment: @Pawel: That's far from the only problem with MFC, and arguably not the worst.